# Failed to load espeak-data xcode 6 with ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I am using espeakEngine project in my project all was running fine before xcode 6 and ios 8.

when i install xcode 6 beta 2 and run my app with iphone4s and other sumulator i am getting this error

**Can't read data file: '/Users/sandeepsharma/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D05D7879-FB45-4E0C-B03A-0AB4202E1608/data/Applications/6B68F910-5822-47E5-B645-99BF4F8DE/phontab'
Failed to load espeak-data**

I am surprise the path with this line
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

this line give with xcode 5.0 with ios 7  "/Users/sandeepsharma/Library/Application

Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/66286A80-A5C7-4FB7-BEC7-E43C716017DD/TestApp.app"

and With xcode 6 with ios8

"/Users/sandeepsharma/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D05D7879-FB45-4E0C-B03A-0AB4202E1608/data/Applications/6B68F910-5822-47E5-B645-99BF4F8DEC94/TestApp.app"

Please help me i am stucking on this i this this the only path problem with ios 8.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but I'm posting the answer in case others run into it, as I did. I wasn't able to find an answer anywhere.

The cause of this problem in Xcode 6 with iOS 8 can be found on or near line 75 in the espeak_1.0/Libraries/speech.h file. Xcode 6's simulator application path turns out to be longer than the size defined. The fastest fix is to change

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#define N_PATH_HOME  220
#else
#define N_PATH_HOME  150
#endif
```

to this:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#define N_PATH_HOME  220
#else
#define N_PATH_HOME  220
#endif
```

Or, better yet, get rid of the conditional and keep only one line:

```
#define N_PATH_HOME  220
```

The path was being truncated when 150 was the size. Change it to 220 and it works (at least with my directory structure and resulting paths).